# Последовательное переключение слайдов

Tags: jquery

Как прописать последовательное переключение слайдов по клику на `.prev` и `.next`? То есть, чтобы при клике на `.next`, всплывающее окно `#popup-box-a` заменялось на `#popup-box-b` и т.д. При клике на `.prev`, соответственно, в обратную сторону.

И зациклить круг, чтобы после последнего открывалось `#popup-box-a`. Пробовала через `name.length`, но я не очень дружу с jquery.

Вот кусочек кода.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('body').append('<div class="prev" id="prev-a"></div><div class="popup-box" id="popup-box-a"><img class="artbigpic" src="../IMG/arts/ami.png" /></div><div class="next" id="next-a"></div>');
    $('body').append('<div class="prev" id="prev-b"></div><div class="popup-box" id="popup-box-b"><img class="artbigpic" src="../IMG/arts/chibi_chibi.jpg" /></div><div class="next" id="next-b"></div>');
    $('body').append('<div class="prev" id="prev-c"></div><div class="popup-box" id="popup-box-c"><img class="artbigpic" src="../IMG/arts/screaming.jpg" /></div><div class="next" id="next-c"></div>');
    $('body').append('<div class="prev" id="prev-d"></div><div class="popup-box" id="popup-box-d"><img class="artbigpic" src="../IMG/arts/knight.png" /></div><div class="next" id="next-d"></div>');
    $('body').append('<div class="prev" id="prev-e"></div><div class="popup-box" id="popup-box-e"><img class="artbigpic" src="../IMG/arts/nahraen.jpg" /></div><div class="next" id="next-e"></div>');
    $('body').append('<div class="prev" id="prev-f"></div><div class="popup-box" id="popup-box-f"><img class="artbigpic" src="../IMG/arts/regina.png" /></div><div class="next" id="next-f"></div>');
    $('body').append('<div class="prev" id="prev-g"></div><div class="popup-box" id="popup-box-g"><img class="artbigpic" src="../IMG/arts/rin.png" /></div><div class="next" id="next-g"></div>');
    $('body').append('<div class="prev" id="prev-h"></div><div class="popup-box" id="popup-box-h"><img class="artbigpic" src="../IMG/arts/luara.png" /></div><div class="next" id="next-h"></div>');
    $('body').append('<div class="prev" id="prev-i"></div><div class="popup-box" id="popup-box-i"><img class="artbigpic" src="../IMG/arts/moulin_rouge.jpg" /></div><div class="next" id="next-i"></div>');
    $('body').append('<div class="prev" id="prev-j"></div><div class="popup-box" id="popup-box-j"><img class="artbigpic" src="../IMG/arts/DA_contest.png" /></div><div class="next" id="next-j"></div>');
    $('body').append('<div class="prev" id="prev-k"></div><div class="popup-box" id="popup-box-k"><img class="artbigpic" src="../IMG/arts/owl.jpg" /></div><div class="next"> id="next-k"</div>');
    $('body').append('<div class="prev" id="prev-l"></div><div class="popup-box" id="popup-box-l"><img class="artbigpic" src="../IMG/arts/eva.png" /></div><div class="next" id="next-l"></div>');
    $('body').append('<div class="prev" id="prev-m"></div><div class="popup-box" id="popup-box-m"><img class="artbigpic" src="../IMG/arts/me.jpg" /></div><div class="next" id="next-m"></div>');
    $('body').append('<div class="prev" id="prev-n"></div><div class="popup-box" id="popup-box-n"><img class="artbigpic" src="../IMG/arts/winter.jpg" /></div><div class="next" id="next-n"></div>');
    $('body').append('<div class="prev" id="prev-o"></div><div class="popup-box" id="popup-box-o"><img class="artbigpic" src="../IMG/arts/minako.jpg" /></div><div class="next" id="next-o"></div>');
    $('body').append('<div class="prev" id="prev-p"></div><div class="popup-box" id="popup-box-p"><img class="artbigpic" src="../IMG/arts/moon_fairy.jpg" /></div><div class="next" id="next-p"></div>');
    $('body').append('<div class="prev" id="prev-q"></div><div class="popup-box" id="popup-box-q"><img class="artbigpic" src="../IMG/arts/flower_fairy.png" /></div><div class="next" id="next-q"></div>');
    $('body').append('<div class="prev" id="prev-r"></div><div class="popup-box" id="popup-box-r"><img class="artbigpic" src="../IMG/arts/luara_and_cassandra.jpg" /></div><div class="next" id="next-r"></div>');

    $('[class*=popup-link]').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        var name = $(this).attr('class');
        var id = name[name.length - 1];
        var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();

        $('#popup-box-'+id).show();
        $('#prev-'+id).show();
        $('#next-'+id).show();
        $('html,body').css('overflow', 'hidden');

        $('html').scrollTop(scrollPos);
    });
```

Comment: можно ли менять наименования «popup-box-r» на popup-box-1?

Comment: class popup-link откуда взялся?

Answer (score 1):

Ну зациклить можно как то так, если конечно я правильно понял задачу...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imgSrcArr = [
        "../IMG/arts/ami.png", "../IMG/arts/chibi_chibi.jpg", "../IMG/arts/screaming.jpg",
        "../IMG/arts/knight.png", "../IMG/arts/nahraen.jpg", "../IMG/arts/regina.png",
        "../IMG/arts/rin.png", "../IMG/arts/luara.png", "../IMG/arts/moulin_rouge.jpg",
        "../IMG/arts/DA_contest.png", "../IMG/arts/owl.jpg", "../IMG/arts/eva.png",
        "../IMG/arts/me.jpg", "../IMG/arts/winter.jpg", "../IMG/arts/minako.jpg",
        "../IMG/arts/moon_fairy.jpg", "../IMG/arts/flower_fairy.png", "../IMG/arts/luara_and_cassandra.jpg"
    ];
  
    imgSrcArr.forEach(function(imgSrc, i) {
        var $domElemToAppend = $(
            '<div class="prev" id="prev-' + i + '">prev</div>' +
            '<div class="popup-box" id="popup-box-' + i + '"><img class="artbigpic" src="' + imgSrc + '" alt="' + imgSrc + '"/></div>' +
            '<div class="next" id="next-' + i + '">next</div>'
        );
        $('body').append($domElemToAppend);
        if (i + 1 < imgSrcArr.length) {
            $domElemToAppend.hide();
        };
    });
  
    $('.prev,.next').on('click', function(e) {
        var index = parseInt(e.target.id.split('-')[1]);
        var direction = (e.target.className == 'next') ? 1 : -1;
        var targetIndex = index + direction;
        if (targetIndex < 0) {
            targetIndex = imgSrcArr.length - 1;
        } else if (targetIndex > imgSrcArr.length - 1) {
            targetIndex = 0;
        };    
        var selector = '#prev-' + index + ',#next-' + index + ',#popup-box-' + index +
                       ',#prev-' + targetIndex + ',#next-' + targetIndex + ',#popup-box-' + targetIndex;
        $(selector).toggle();
    })  
});
```

```html
<body><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script></body>
```